# How to control Newport controller model 8742 with python?

Tags: python

I have the Newport New Focus Picomotor Controller/Driver, Model 8742, and it comes with software to control the motors. I want to be able to command the controller with python. There is a similar question here already but for some reason that code is not working for me. So far I have

```
import serial as s
from time import sleep

try:
    s.Serial.close()
except:
    pass
    ser= s.Serial('COMX',baudrate=921600,timeout=1.0,parity=s.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=s.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=s.EIGHTBITS)
    command = '1PAU0.00\r\n'
    bcommand = bytes(command,'UTF-8')
    a = ser.write(bcommand)
    sleep(0.1)
    print(ser.read(10))
    ser.close()
```

Part of the problem is that I'm not sure what port number I put in the code where 'COMX' is inserted. This is my first time using python for serial communication, so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is really a programming issue (yet). You need to find out what COM port the device is connected to. That will come from your OS.

Comment: I know nothing about that controller, and can merely hope your serial port is capable of that rather unusual baud rate, but the name of the serial port isn't a Python issue at all. It's dependent on your operating system and computer.

Comment: Yes you guys are right but once I got the correct COM port, the error I got is                                                                                                     raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))

SerialException: could not open port '54489': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.').                                                           Any help on  that? @glibdud

Comment: @P.Kaur do you know where I could find more resource and examples for this controller?

Answer (score 0):

The USB driver for 8742 / 8743 controllers does not expose an actual serial port. However,  you can communicate using ASCII commands thru its [USB endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-endpoints-and-their-pipes) on any operating system, which can be done with PyUSB. Here's an excellent starting point: https://github.com/bdhammel/python_newport_controller